# How to directly capture images from a built-in webcam in a web application?

Tags: webcam, twain

I already have a web application that allows my clients to scanner documents from scanners with TWAIN drivers installed, save scanned documents as PDF locally or upload to web server.

One thing I would like my web application to support is capturing images from built-in webcam. It seems there aren't or very few webcams that support TWAIN.

Any suggestions to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use something other that TWAIN, WIA is probably the easiest way to grab an image, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306929/take-a-picture-automatically-using-a-webcam-in-c-sharp-using-wia)

Comment: Thank you. I found [this SDK](http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/webcam-sdk.aspx) which is based on [DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375454(v=vs.85).aspx). It seems to work for me.

Answer (score 3):

If your camera does not have a twain driver and your applications are not "seeing" it, you will have to use a 3rd party solution that comes in between the camera and your application. I am using terminalworks' Unitwain as I am already using some of their other scanning products. I must say that it helped me a lot cause I already had a lot of web cameras installed but no twain drivers available for our new business application.

edit: i forgot to include a link to the site: http://www.terminalworks.com/unitwain